# Noise and ripple values in a bench power supply

Tags: power-supply, noise

I was trying to analyse the Vpp and Vrms of a bench power supply. Now, I understand that Vrms = Vpp * 0.707.

Now, the bench power under study is the [GPD-4303S](http://www.gwinstek.com/en-global/products/DC_Power_Supply/Programmable_Multiple_Channel_DC_Power_Supplies/GPD-Series).

The Vrms and Vpp is given as shown below -

[image: Values]

Now, Vpp = 10mV. So the positive is 5mV.
Henceforth Vrms = 0.707*5mV = 3.53mV.
How come they have 1mV as Vrms ?

Kindly clarify this please.

Comment: Vrms is NOT Vpp*0.707 unless the ripple is a perfect sine. (It usually isn't).  As Peter points out below ripple is periodic (50/60 Hz, or the switching frequency on a SMPS for example) where noise is wide spectrum random disturbances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ripple and Noise are two separate measurements.

The ripple voltage on the DC output of the supply is under 1 mV RMS (not counting any random noise).

The noise voltage (independent of ripple) is under 10 mVpp.